# Possible bug in Boost 1.65.1. while running bootstrap.bat gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, boost

While running `bootstrap.bat gcc` after extracting it I got the next error in `bootstrap.log`:

```
...
 \boost_1_65_1\tools\build\src\engine>.\bootstrap\jam0 -f build.jam
 --toolset=gcc "--toolset-root= "   
 ...found 161 targets... 
 ...updating 3 targets... 
 [MKDIR] bin.ntx86_64 
 [COMPILE] bin.ntx86_64\b2.exe
 debugger.c: In function 'debug_start_child': 
 debugger.c:1128:5: error:
 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
      for ( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i )
      ^
 debugger.c:1128:5: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code 
 strings.c: In function 'string_rtrim':
 strings.c:195:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
 [-Wpedantic]
      char * p = self->value + self->size - 1;
      ^
 ...
```

Modifying `boost_1_65_1\tools\build\src\engine\debugger.c:1128` I get a proper build.

I track the compilation command to `boost_1_65_1\tools\build\src\engine\config_toolset.bat:204`. So by adding `--std=c99` I can also solve it (although I get warnings and compilation fails).

I didn't find a report at `https://svn.boost.org/trac10/search?ticket=on`.

Can someone with more experience confirm this? And report it, if necessary.

Windows 10 - 64bits.
Mingw-w64 (gcc 4.8.3).
Boost 1.65.1.

Comment: Boost is a ***C++*** thing, you probably shouldn't be trying to compile it with a C compiler in *any* mode :-)

Comment: You're right. But I add the gcc option because of this Getting Started on Windows (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) and this one (https://gist.github.com/sim642/29caef3cc8afaa273ce6). The gcc toolset is for MinGW and Cygwin.

Comment: Current C-standard is ISO/IEC 9899:2011, so try `--std=c11` for the C-part of the code. If that works you can file a bug that the build-script is brocken/old.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug report for this problem: https://svn.boost.org/trac10/ticket/13252

I didn't file it, but now if anyone comes across this question and wonders if it has been reported, it has.

In the meantime while it's being addressed, I think that the easiest way to get past it is as Black Arrow suggested above, to go to the file: `boost_1_65_1\tools\build\src\engine\debugger.c`, line 1128, and change:

```
for ( int i = 1; i < argc; ++i )
```

to:

```
int i;
for ( i = 1; i < argc; ++i )
```

save it, then run `bootsrtap gcc`

Comment: I completely forgot about this. I filed and I was waiting for an answer. Thanks, there should be a reference to it.